# Bootstrap 3.1.1 doesn't work on MVC3 View page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new in MVC.NET and I have this problem:

I'm trying to create a simple button that shows a Bootstrap modal dialog but it doesn't work. The bootstrap version is 3.1.1 and jquery 1.9.0.

_Layout.cshtml references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.9.0.js")"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css")"/>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css")" />
```

Index.cshtml code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
    <div id="example" class="modal fade" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                 <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
                <p>You can add some text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The .css file is loaded because I can see that the styles are applied but bootstrap.js or jquery aren't and the dialog doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you verified that your script paths are correct and coming down correctly?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console and the paths are ok, I checked. When I click the button, the of ID the div element is added to URL like this: http://localhost:port/#example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. JQuery library must be declared before bootstrap library. It seems that there is an order to follow or something like that.

Comment: It is because the bootstrap js file uses jquery.

Comment: Obviously, but as I said JQuery must be defined before bootstrap.js

Comment: Yes, and I was explaining why. I find giving an explanation for why something is happening is better than just saying what needs to be fixed. When one piece of javascript references another one, the one that is referenced needs to come first in the page, otherwise it will fail. jQuery is referenced in the bootstrap file, which is _why_ jQuery needs to be first.